# AVFoundation barcode scanner working great on iphone but not so well on an Ipad 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, avfoundation

I created a barcode scanner using the `AVFoundation`. It works great with my **iphone 6s plus** and also on **iphone 5** but when i try to use it with **Ipad 2** it barely scans.

I use the rectOfinterest to set the area to scan and if i increase the height of the scan area **(from 4 to 40 points)** it gets a little better but it is not close to how good it works on the iphones

I know the camera is a lot better on the phones so that is probably the reason for this but Im just wondering if there is any way that I can improve the scanning on the ipad?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think the iPad 2 camera has autofocus, meaning scanning barcodes isn't really possible.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen so far with barcode scanning on iOS 10, using `rectOfInterest` is causing a problem on iPads that makes barcode scanning completely unreliable (mostly broken). I can confirm that this happens for EAN-13, Code 39, and Code 128, and possibly other kinds of barcode types.

The solution is to not use `rectOfInterest` at all, and direct the user's attention to the centre of the camera feed, which is the default focus location for barcode scanning.